# What do the packages amsmath and libertine do that prevents counters from working?

Tags: counters, incompatibility

So I have been using a custom setup of counters after some great help on here (thank you, egreg).

The thing is, I have been running into a really odd problem with the counters which I am just unable to reproduce and pinpoint in a reliable way. But I finally have found the culprits... I think.

Is there a way I can use `libertine` and `amsmath` in a reliable fashion so I do not have this experience? Or did I perhaps mis-configure som

## Picture 1 with counters not working

Compiled with `amsmath` and `libertine` loaded so the counters do not work:

[image]

## Picture 2 with counters working

Compiled with `amsmath` and `libertine` commented out:

[image]

## MWE

```
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
DIV=15,
twoside,
headings=normal,
parskip=single,
twopage,
]
{scrartcl}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{
multicol,
setspace,
enumitem,
xcntperchap,
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% the problematic package
\usepackage[oldstyle,proportional]{libertine}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[scaled=0.832]{beramono}
\usepackage[scale=0.8558]{tgheros}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pdfgentounicode=1

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%    A4    %%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{TOTALcounter} % for 'total' counters
\newcounter{counterPERsection}[section]
\RegisterTrackCounter{section}{counterPERsection}
\newcounter{questioncounter}
\RegisterTrackCounter{TOTALcounter}{questioncounter}
% initialize the total counters
\stepcounter{TOTALcounter}
\newcommand{\flashc}[2]{%
\noindent\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}%
\stepcounter{counterPERsection}%
\arabic{counterPERsection}.%
\ObtainTrackedValueExp{section}{counterPERsection}%
\newline
\stepcounter{questioncounter}\arabic{questioncounter}.%
\ObtainTrackedValueExp{TOTALcounter}{questioncounter}\newline%
{#1}%
\end{minipage}}\\[2pt]
#2\vspace{3pt}}

\newcommand{\personone}{\subsection{Stuff by Person1}}
\newcommand{\stufftwo}{\subsection{Stuff by Person2}}
\newcommand{\stuffthree}{\subsection{Stuff by Person3}}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{AAAAAAAA}
\personone
\flashc{444444444444}{}

\flashc{444444444444}{}

\stufftwo
\flashc{444444444444}{}
\flashc{gggggggggggggg}{}
\stuffthree
\flashc{gggggggggggggg}{}
\flashc{ggggggg}{}

\section{BBBBB}
\personone
\flashc{gggggggggggggg!}{}
\flashc{gggggggggggggg}{}
\stufftwo

\flashc{444444444444}{}
\flashc{ggggggg}{}
\flashc{gggggggggggggg}{}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

## Log

https://pastebin.com/V4yCDGtz

Comment: libertine is not involved. Load amsmath before `xcntperchap` and hope that this doesn't break the amsmath usage of the counters.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you please provide your comment as a reply so I could mark the thread/problem as solved? (And yes, I do really hope and pray that this issue won't pop up again!).

Comment: If you compile this on XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, `libertine  will load `fontspec` and prevent either `tgheros` or `beramono` from working. You can fix this either by loading those in `fontspec` as well (`\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase} \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros} \setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}`) or by adding the `type1` option to `libertine`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, as Ulrike Fischer said, but something to be aware of.

Comment: @Davislor ... well ok, thanks, but this is clearly outside of the scope of this thread.

Comment: But, I thought, appropriate for a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`amsmath` (or more precisely `amstext`) redefines `\stepcounter` and so overwrites the changes from `xcntperchap`. If you load amsmath before `xcntperchap` it will probably work (if the additions of `xcntperchap` don't confuse amsmath somewhere.